# Adding pixel tracking to a link

Tags: javascript, html

I had a marketing company send me a bunch of 1x1 pixel tracking images to add to a page. These all work fine, no issues.

They also wanted one of the trackers added to a link that goes out to another page, which is where the problem is.

Heres an example of the pixel tracker: (Actual link removed)

```
<img class="fmfjfemzqkmxnkeezyst" width="1" height="1"   src="//insight.adsrvr.org/track/conv/123" alt="" style="border-style:none;">
```

How exactly can I add this to a link that needs to fire when clicked? My initial thought was to add "src" straight to the "a tag" but looking back, this doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the image to the DOM so that it renders on click of the link, while preventing the default until after the tracker appends:

```
$("a#imgtracker").click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("body").append('<img class="fmfjfemzqkmxnkeezyst" width="1" height="1"   src="//insight.adsrvr.org/track/conv/123" alt="" style="border-style:none;">');

    location.href = $(this).attr("href"); //or hardcode the url here

});
```

Comment: Ah ok. Essentially, when the link is clicked. It grabs that img, hits the "src" and says "Ok someones trying to grab this image" and then sends us off to the linked page. This looks brilliant and it may be my answer.

Comment: Yes, the image is rendered right before user navigates to destination page. Test that it works before you call it "brilliant" :)